# is たがる here correct?

Tags: grammar, nuances

> 誰かゲームを遊びたがっている?

i thought this たがる is for making assumptions, therefore i find weird that someone would say "does somebody seem like wanting to play..."? or am i wrong? is it correct?, if yes, can i also say 誰かゲームを遊びたい? if yes, which one is more natural? if both are unnatural, how would you rewrite it, for it to be natural?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the relevant point here is *who is being asked* this question.

If you are asking somebody directly if they themselves want to do something, then using 〜たい is fine, because you are asking for them to tell you themselves what their own desires are.

However, if you are asking a third person if somebody else wants to do something, they are not really qualified to speak (authoritatively) on behalf of somebody else's feelings or desires.  All they can do is tell you whether it *seems to them* like that person wants to do it or not.  That is what 〜がる indicates, so in that case, you would ask the question using 〜たがる instead of 〜たい.

So「誰かゲームを遊びたがっている？」sounds to me like something somebody would be asking someone about some other people ("Do *any of them* (seem like they) want to play a game?").  On the other hand,「誰かゲームを遊びたい？」would be something you might ask a group of people directly ("Do *any of you* want to play a game?")